# Is there a term used for the collection of a key and value in a C# dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

simple question, I want to know if there's a word/term used to describe the collection/pair of a key and value in a C# Dictionary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is known, simply, as a [Key-Value Pair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx). You can see it when iterating over a Dictionary with `foreach` - each resulting object in the loop is of type `KeyValuePair<K,V>`.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.